# Android settings and preferences

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have set up my settings activity and when running my emulation I can edit my setting.. close the app and start it again and it stays the same all fine.
Now when I want to reference this from an activity textview, I get the key I first wrote into strings.xml which is unitnumkey, yet the settings activity stores it fine..

What exactly am I missing here?

here is pref_general.xml

```
android:key="@string/pref_file_key_unit_number"
        android:title="@string/pref_title_unit_number"
        android:defaultValue="@string/pref_default_unit_number"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLines="1" />
```

Strings.xml

```
<string name="pref_header_general">General</string>
<string name="pref_title_unit_number">Unit SMS Number</string>
<string name="pref_default_unit_number">0756745745</string>
<string name="pref_file_key_unit_number">unitnumKey</string>
```

textview activity

```
String phoneNum = getString(R.string.pref_file_key_unit_number);

                final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                mTextView.setText(phoneNum);
```

settingsactivity

```
public static class GeneralPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);



        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("unitnumKey"));
    }


private static void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
        // Set the listener to watch for value changes.
        preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener);

        // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's
        // current value.
        sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(preference,
                PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                        .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
    }
```

Comment: What is bindPreferenceSummaryToValue ?  and it looks like you must be using a different Library than the Android Library for PreferenceFragment, this type of information is always helpful

Comment: I am using a settingsactivity template... I added some code about the bindpref

Comment: Sorry, please see my update 2 there where i use `myValue` in setText

Comment: @inner_class7 are you a wizard? thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your not opening preferences at all, your just reading the String value out.

You need to do:
**UPDATE 2**

```
  String phoneNum = getString(R.string.pref_file_key_unit_number);
  SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
  String myValue = preferences.getString(phoneNum, null);

  final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
  mTextView.setText(myValue);
```

Comment: @JayBoy please see update, try passing `getApplicationContext()` instead of `this` when getting default shared preferences, also please provide the code where your storing the preference